# Ошибка MySql 1052 Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

При выполнении запроса возникла ошибка:  Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 SELECT item.*
 FROM item
 JOIN price ON price.item = item.id
 JOIN currency ON currency.id = price.currency
 WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `item_id` FROM `item_code` WHERE `number` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `number` WHERE `mark`='3')) 
 ORDER BY price.price * currency.course 
 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: у  вас дублирующие записии скорее всего в запросе сделайте distinct.

Comment: Как например? (Спасибо)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT  `id` FROM `number` WHERE `mark`='3'` так попробуй но я не шарю в sql я только php

Comment: Не думаю что проблема в этом.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по запросу, поле id есть как минимум в 2х таблицах (item и currency)

В `WHERE` вам нужно указать по id из какой таблицы вы хотите отфильтровать.

Если это item то запрос должен быть таким:

```
 SELECT item.*
 FROM item
 JOIN price ON price.item = item.id
 JOIN currency ON currency.id = price.currency
 WHERE item.`id` IN (SELECT `item_id` FROM `item_code` WHERE `number` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `number` WHERE `mark`='3')) 
 ORDER BY price.price * currency.course 
 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось)